# GetContentStream alternative in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my asp.net application there is a menu built from an xml file. The menu uses a XmlDataSource with the `DataFile = "~/App_Data/SideMenu.xml"`. That file has properties `"Build Action"=Content` and `"Copy to Output Directory"="Do not copy"`.

Now I want to use this file in my own code, and I tried to open it with GetContentStream, but that doesn't seem to be possible in asp.net (problem with Application object). I am a bit reulctant to change the settings for the file.

What are my options? (XmlDataSource obviously does it)

Comment: So you want to use a file, but you don't want to make it available for the program?

Comment: Sure, it is obviously avaliable to the program when building the menu. I thought the right thing would to do, would be to do it as the menu datasource does it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step as you already mentioned is to set `Build Action = Content` for the file.

Then to read the file you can use `HttpServerUtilityBase.MapPath` to get the physical file path. From within an ASP.NET MVC controller you can simply use the `Server` property:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/SideMenu.xml"));
```

Or access it from the `Server` property on the global `HttpContext.Current` object.